# Leg structure in a shallow sea world

Tags: creature-design, xenobiology, aliens

I am currently building an alien planet that is based around a creative drawing exercise, where I drew an alien with different bug like features. They are bipedal humanoids, but along with other differences, have sticklike lower legs. I then thought of environments were this could be useful and I landed on a planet covered in shallow seas and lakes. Along with their taller physique, the thin legs would help them move around more easily in the mud and water. But I am reconsidering this choice on account of a realistic world. I would like to keep the shallow sea world, but my question comes down to: would it be possible to have these type of legs, what environment would these legs develop in, and what type of legs could be a better fit?

Edit: A few more details about the world and the aliens. The aliens are about 7' 2-7". Their lower legs would be close to the width of a bone, if a little thicker, with a hard exoskeleton. I haven't really thought about the gravity on their planet, but part of the story would be set on Earth. The planet would be covered in very large lakes that are only a few feet shallow, like larger rice paddys.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you add the drawing?  You are asking what sort of ecosystem your being would evolve in.  Let's have a look!

Comment: Sorry! I can't figure out how to add a photo and all the photos from my computer are very hard to see. :(

Comment: Asking "would it be possible to have these type of legs, what environment would these legs develop in, and what type of legs could be a better fit?" is way too broad, and the last question doesn't make sense (the environment these legs develop in will necessarily be the best fit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Wading birds have long legs.**

[image: heron]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_blue_heron

The long legs keep the body out of the water.  There are reasons why it might be nice to not be down in the water.  It might be cold.  There might be things in the water that will bother you.  You can attack your prey from above with a different sort of attack than is possible at water level.

Long legs also make you taller and you can see farther.  I have read that the reason for the super long legs of the maned wolf is to get it up over the tall grass of the pampas to see what is going on.  Maybe your creatures live in a planet of grass?

Perhaps a more interesting use of long legs would be as weapons.  That is different from how we usually think of hominids.  Secretary birds use their long legs to kill prey.

[image: secretary bird skeleton]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretarybird

I propose your hominids kill things by kicking them up into the air, possibly into the mouths of their compadres.  These hominids also conduct intraspecific warfare largely by kicking.  The range of kicks used is culturally determined, with some groups using an amazing array of kicks and some limiting themselves only to groin kicks.  The hands are dainty and delicate and used only for fine work, not fighting.